# When was the first documented mention of mechanically generated electricity?

Tags: technology, sources

Electricity seems to have become known and adapted widespread in the early 19th century. With people such as Nikola Tesla and Thomas Alva Edison it eventually entered our daily lives as a source of light and warmth.

**Q**: When/What was the first documented mention of *mechanically* generated electricity?

By *mechanically* I mean electricity generated through mechanical action (e.g. a wheel turning).

---

This question is asking about cases where the generated electricity has furthermore been used to power any contraption with, at least, an apparent use e.g.:

- powering a [spark-gap transmitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark-gap_transmitter) to make electricity visible
  -> **cool**
- creating a charge that eventually unloads itself through touch or something like that
  -> **not cool**

Comment: If you count static electricity, from the time of the old Greeks.

Comment: @SJuan76 even though I assume the [tag:sources] tag to be a request for some citations, you're showing up a valid issue; I will amend my question to ask for mechanically generated electricity used to `power` something that had a use other than experimenting with energy

Comment: Given the revision in the above comment, it would seem that wikipedia has the [answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woolrich_Electrical_Generator). I.e. *The Woolrich Electrical Generator...is the earliest electrical generator used in an industrial process*

Comment: @SteveBird well, why not add it as an answer then..?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T I didn't add it as an answer because I couldn't do a better job than the wikipedia page and the [policy](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here is to not simply duplicate existing online sources. (see: Questions answered by a simple Google search or to be found in a Wikipedia page).

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the two examples.  If wikipedia answers the question, then the question is trivial.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace if you're referring to the examples in my question: The idea behind the two examples is to better explain what I am looking to find/hoping for you people on here to help me find; the purpose of examples is to narrow down a question. So I am not asking about the first mention of someone stumbling over carpet and then fizzling their neighbour by shaking hands but about the first documented use of a machine to generate electricity in order to power something

Comment: Also @Downvoter, it would be great if you could leave a comment explaining why the downvote so I can improve the question to your liking. Even bad feedback is better than none...

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I'll move myself to the general chat and try to answer your points there

Comment: I'd agree that you definitely need to clarify what the question is. The title asks for "first documented mention of mechanically generated electricity", the body of the question then says "used to power any contraption with, at least, an apparent use" with an example that would "make electricity visible". Then in a comment it's "used to power something that had a use other than experimenting", which rules out most of Faraday's work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the text of the question differs from the text of the comment. The question says that if you hook a generator up to a spark gap transmitter it is cool, but if you hook the same generator up to a person and shock the person who touches them, then it is not cool. Several of us have asked why Faraday's generators mentioned in wikipedia don't (trivially) answer the question. The phrase "seems like" calls attention to the fact that there is no preliminary research.

Comment: By "mechanical action" if the author means a generator...meaning a magnet wrapped in copper wire being spun using a turbine blade I would say in Edison NJ in a lab. Much depends on AC versus DC and the creation of a circuit ("the light switch") which I think would need to be specified first. In short "Westinghouse or General Electric." You also need the glass bulb, filament and vacuum (the "light bulb") and something to regulate a consistent flow of electrons (the substation.) plus insulation, insulators, guy wired and poles...the list is quite long before you can simply flip the switch.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean electromagnetic generator, it was first designed by Faraday
(see Wikipedia, "Electric generator") and it is called the Faraday disk.

But strictly speaking, you can "mechanically generate electricity" in another way:
by rubbing a piece of glass or another substance. This is known since antiquity.
A machine with wheels, called friction generator was invented by Otto von Guericke
in 1663. See Wikipedia "Electrostatic generator".

Comment: I think that Faraday's work was significant because it produced current that could be transmitted and used for work; I am not positive but I don't static electricity could be. Prior to Faraday, electricity for experimentation came from batteries and so Faraday's work was hugely important.

Comment: Current from a battery also can be transmitted and used to do work.

Comment: Yes, from a battery but I think *static* electricity can't be used to make an electromagnet or at least in a practical way. Mechanically generated electricity that could generated in a predictable and over an arbitrarily long period was key to advances in other areas of electrical research.